# ocamlfind does not find a package installed with godi

Tags: installation, debian, ocaml, godi, ocamlfind

I tried to compile a OMakefile with omake.
I installed all needed packages with GODI.
GODI shows me these packages as installed.
Ocamlfind does not find all of these packages.
With ocamlfind list it show only some.

The packages it did not find are: batteries and ocamlgraph. Has anyone an idea to solve this problem. My target is it to use a program that someone else has created.

Greetings

Sven

```
    root@debian:/# ocamlfind list
    bigarray            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.exceptiontracer (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.extend       (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.foldgenerator (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.gramlib      (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.lib          (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.listcomprehension (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.locationstripper (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.macro        (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.mapgenerator (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.metagenerator (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.profiler     (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.quotations   (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.quotations.o (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.quotations.r (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    camlp4.tracer       (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    dbm                 (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    dynlink             (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    extlib              (version: 1.5)
    findlib             (version: 1.2.5)
    graphics            (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    labltk              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    num                 (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    num-top             (version: 1.2.5)
    num.core            (version: [internal])
    sexplib             (version: 4.2.16)
    sexplib.core        (version: n/a)
    sexplib.syntax      (version: n/a)
    sexplib.top         (version: n/a)
    stdlib              (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    str                 (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    threads             (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
    threads.posix       (version: [internal])
    threads.vm          (version: [internal])
    type-conv           (version: 1.7.1)
    type-conv.syntax    (version: 1.7.1)
    unix                (version: [distributed with Ocaml])
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the ocamlfind command provided by your GODI installation? My guess is that you are using the one provided by Debian.

To see which one you are using, run `which ocamlfind`. If it returns `/usr/bin/ocamlfind`, then you are using the Debian one. To use the GODI one, you need to adjust your `PATH` environment variable; for this, put:

```
export PATH=/path/to/godi/bin:$PATH
```

in e.g. your `~/.bashrc`.

By the way, batteries and ocamlgraph are available as Debian package; you might want to try them first.

Comment: Normaly i use ocamlfind of GODI and the PATH is set. I tried the ocamlfind of debian without setting my PATH to GODI/bin. The output of both ocamlfind are the same *wonder*. I will do a backup and try the Debian packages.

Comment: It works with the debian package, but now i need the package bin_prot, which is not part of Debian. Any idea?

Comment: bin_prot is in Debian: http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libbin-prot-camlp4-dev